# Error while registering a new Postgres server using pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[image: error while creating a new server]

I am getting error while registering a new server on my newly installed pgadmin 4.  kindly help me to get out of this error.  thank you in advance

Comment: You are trying to connect with the username (aka 'role') of 'postgres', but that role doesn't exist.  Change the username to one that does exist.

Comment: yes.. I got it.. I was connecting with wrong username...